# How to have current value from database selected in DropDownListFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, html.dropdownlistfor

I have a `Shop` model:

```
public class Shop
{
    public int ShopId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Winkel")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

And a model for the `Weekday`:

```
public class WeekDay
{
    public int WeekDayId { get; set; } // Integers from 0 to 6 where Sunday is 0 and Saturday 6
                                 // so that it maps with the DayOfWeek enumeration
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Dag")]
    public string Day { get; set; }

    public int? ShopId { get; set; }
    public virtual Shop Shop { get; set; }
}
```

Now my goal is to display the seven days with next to them a dropdownlist with the possible shops to choose from. I want to be able to show the current shop that belongs to the day selected in a `Html.DropDownList(For)` currently selected in the dropdownlist. The next and final step is to be able to click a button and save all the currently selected values and update the `WeekDay` table in the database, which looks like this:

> ```
> WeekDayId    ShopId    Day
> 1            NULL      Zondag
> 2            1         Maandag
> 3            1         Dinsdag
> 4            1         Woensdag
> 5            1         Donderdag
> 6            2         Vrijdag
> 7            NULL      Zaterdag
> ```

To do this I made the following ViewModel:

```
public class ShopWeekDayViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Shop> ShopItems { get; set; }
    public List<WeekDay> WeekDays { get; set; }
}
```

And then in the view I display the different `WeekDay`s with the `Shop`s as follows:

```
@model ViewModels.ShopWeekDayViewModel

<table>
@foreach (var weekDay in Model.WeekDays)
    {
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                   @Html.DisplayFor(d => weekDay.Day)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => weekDay.Shop.ShopId, 
                        new SelectList(Model.ShopItems, 
                                     "ShopId", 
                                     "Name", 
                                     Model.ShopItems), 
                      "")
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    }
</table>
```

Now the current value (from the database - so the actual shop that is currently connected with the weekday) in the `DropDownListFor` is not selected, and I do not know how to accomplish this goal. I hope someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => weekDay.Shop.ShopId, 
    new SelectList(Model.ShopItems, 
        "ShopId", 
        "Name", 
        weekDay.Shop.ShopId)
)
```

The last parameter to the `SelectList` constructor is an `object` which represents the selected value.  Currently, you're passing in an `IEnumerable` for that parameter, which doesn't make any sense as you want to select a single value.  Also notice that I'm using `weekDay.Shop.ShopId`, instead of `Model.Shop.ShopId`, in order to reference the `Shop` that belongs to the current `WeekDay`.

Comment: Works! Only issue now is that my weekDay.Shop.ShopId can be null, I want to be able to return an empty value if it is null but cannot nest `if`-statements or use the `??` operator in the `SelectList`. :-) Thanks!

Comment: @user2609980 Populate `ShopItems` in the controller first, setting the values as desired and then use that as the `SelectList` in the view as it currently stands.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting your `SelectList` selected value to your list of items.

Change it to use a different overload an dnot have a selected value

```
new SelectList(Model.ShopItems, "ShopId", "Name")
```

So you view becomes:

@model ViewModels.ShopWeekDayViewModel

```
<table>
@foreach (var weekDay in Model.WeekDays)
    {
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                   @Html.DisplayFor(d => weekDay.Day)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => weekDay.Shop.ShopId, 
                        new SelectList(Model.ShopItems, 
                                     "ShopId", 
                                     "Name"))
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    }
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but when I use your edit they all have the default value (the first shop). So this does not work. Maybe you misunderstood the question: I want to have the actual database value selected in the `DropDownList`...